# How to create PDF file using iText or some other library on android?

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, pdflib

How to create PDF file using iText or some other library on android?

Is there any tutorial on iText for android?

Thanks

Comment: What are you creating the PDF from? I am unfamiliar with `iText`.

Comment: No, I want to create an PDF file in an android application using text & images.

Answer (score 14):

You can use iText to create PDFs. Use the latest version (5.1.3) and include only the itextpdf-5.1.3.jar in the build path. You can use something like this to accomplish the pdf creation.

```
Document document = new Document();
file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Hello.pdf"
PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(file));
document.open();
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Hello PDF");
document.add(p);
document.close();
```

Also, don't forget to use the permission to write to external storage in the manifest.xml.

Comment: getting error here.....PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(file));
tell me the possible solution

Comment: People here can help you better if you post the error. And downvoting just because a solution didn't work for you is not the way to go. Please spend some time learning the code of conduct before you post something. Also nobody is going to walk you through a solution without you having tried to debug it at least a little bit on your own.

Comment: same code i am using, in console it is showing proper format, but after creating PDF alignment is not proper

Answer (score 12):

It's Easy,For example

[Here](https://github.com/David-Hackro/ExamplesAndroid/tree/master/PDF/Creacion%20PDF) the Code in my repository (updated link)

**gradle.build**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.madgag:scpkix-jdk15on:1.47.0.1'
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.0.6'
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hackro.itext.MainActivity">
    
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnwrite"
        android:text="PDF"
        android:onClick="GeneratePDF"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "GeneratePDF";


    private BaseFont bfBold;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    }


    public void GeneratePDF(View view)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String filename = "david";
        String filecontent = "Contenido";
        Metodos fop = new Metodos();
        if (fop.write(filename, filecontent)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    filename + ".pdf created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I/O error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

  }
```

**Metodos.java**

```
 import android.util.Log;
    
    import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
    import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    /**
     * Created by hackro on 24/11/15.
     */
    public class Metodos {
    
    
        public Boolean write(String fname, String fcontent) {
            try {
                String fpath = "/sdcard/" + fname + ".pdf";
                File file = new File(fpath);
    
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
    
                Font bfBold12 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(0, 0, 0));
                Font bf12 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);
    
    
                Document document = new Document();
    
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                        new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsoluteFile()));
                document.open();
    
                document.add(new Paragraph("Sigueme en Twitter!"));
    
                document.add(new Paragraph("@DavidHackro"));
                document.close();
    
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }}
```

**Result**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Good Luck**

Comment: iTextpdf v5.0.6 is listed as the dependency. I have two issues with that. 1. 5.0.6 is insanely old. Stick to newer versions for new applications. 2. You're using iText Java and not iTextG (Android port). The Android port has a few minor modifications. To name a few: exclude the usage of API that isn't in the Android API (java.awt) and prevention of namespace clashing (BouncyCastle).

Comment: yea, I 'm building second example using iTextG ;)

Comment: Well. first of all thank you wish I saw your solution few hours before. Second I need to ask itext is not free isnt it ?

Comment: I used itextg here is the gist I used to create pdf . I added the watermark, image and use table https://gist.github.com/mhd-zulqarnain/ee99c42c4d35dcdcaffd610507f75402

Answer (score 4):

> This is my sample coding for creating pdf file with text and image
>   content using Itext library and to store the pdf file in the external
>   Storage location. The only thing is you need to download the itext
>   library and add it into your project.

```
private void createPdf() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();

                 try {
                        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/vindroid";

                        File dir = new File(path);
                            if(!dir.exists())
                                dir.mkdirs();

                        Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);


                        File file = new File(dir, "sample.pdf");
                        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

                        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fOut);

                        //open the document
                        document.open();


                        Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Sample PDF CREATION USING IText");
                        Font paraFont= new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER);
                        p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
                        p1.setFont(paraFont);

                         //add paragraph to document    
                         document.add(p1);

                         Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("This is an example of a simple paragraph");
                         Font paraFont2= new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER,14.0f,0, CMYKColor.GREEN);
                         p2.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
                         p2.setFont(paraFont2);

                         document.add(p2);

                         ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , stream);
                         Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
                         myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

                         //add image to document
                         document.add(myImg);




                 } catch (DocumentException de) {
                         Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                         Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
                 } 
                 finally
                 {
                         document.close();
                 }

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a sample project for creating the pdf file from data using **itextpdf/itext7 library**

Example project link: https://github.com/rheyansh/RPdfGenerator

Add below dependancy in your application gradle:

```
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.12'
```

**Important Notes**

Add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Add File Provider in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.rheyansh.rpdfgenerator.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Add XML resource folder (see provider_paths.xml in example folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Create RPdfGenerator class

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Environment
import com.rheyansh.model.RTransaction
import android.widget.Toast
import com.itextpdf.io.font.constants.StandardFonts
import com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.ColorConstants
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.action.PdfAction
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Text
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.UnitValue
import com.rheyansh.lenden.model.RPdfGeneratorModel
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream

object RPdfGenerator {

    private val linkSample = "https://github.com/rheyansh/RPdfGenerator"

    fun generatePdf(context: Context, info: RPdfGeneratorModel) {

        val FILENAME = info.header + ".pdf"
        val filePath = getAppPath(context) + FILENAME

        if (File(filePath).exists()) {
            File(filePath).delete()
        }

        val fOut = FileOutputStream(filePath)
        val pdfWriter = PdfWriter(fOut)

        // Creating a PdfDocument
        val pdfDocument =
            PdfDocument(pdfWriter)
        val layoutDocument = Document(pdfDocument)

        // title
        addTitle(layoutDocument, info.header)

        //add empty line
        addEmptyLine(layoutDocument,1)

        //Add sub heading
        val appName = "RPdfGenerator"
        addSubHeading(layoutDocument, "Generated via: ${appName}")
        addLink(layoutDocument, linkSample)

        //add empty line
        addEmptyLine(layoutDocument,1)

        // customer reference information
        addDebitCredit(layoutDocument, info)

        //add empty line
        addEmptyLine(layoutDocument,1)

        //Add sub heading
        addSubHeading(layoutDocument, "Transactions")

        //Add list
        addTable(layoutDocument, info.list)

        layoutDocument.close()
        Toast.makeText(context, "Pdf saved successfully to location $filePath", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        //FileUtils.openFile(context, File(filePath))
    }

    private fun getAppPath(context: Context): String {
        val dir = File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString() + File.separator
                    + context.resources.getString(R.string.app_name)
                    + File.separator
        )
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir()
        }
        return dir.path + File.separator
    }

    private fun addTable(layoutDocument: Document, items: List<RTransaction>) {

        val table = Table(
            UnitValue.createPointArray(
                floatArrayOf(
                    100f,
                    180f,
                    80f,
                    80f,
                    80f,
                    100f
                )
            )
        )

        // headers
        //table.addCell(Paragraph("S.N.O.").setBold())
        table.addCell(Paragraph("Item").setBold())
        table.addCell(Paragraph("Customer").setBold())
        table.addCell(Paragraph("Qty").setBold())
        table.addCell(Paragraph("Price/Q").setBold())
        table.addCell(Paragraph("Total").setBold())
        table.addCell(Paragraph("Date").setBold())

        // items
        for (a in items) {
//            table.addCell(Paragraph(a.SNO.toString() + ""))
            table.addCell(Paragraph(a.itemName + ""))
            table.addCell(Paragraph(a.custName + ""))
            table.addCell(Paragraph(a.quantity.toString() + ""))
            table.addCell(Paragraph(a.pricePerUnit.toString() + ""))
            table.addCell(Paragraph((a.quantity * a.pricePerUnit).toString() + ""))
            table.addCell(Paragraph(a.transactionDateStr + ""))
        }
        layoutDocument.add(table)
    }

    private fun addEmptyLine(layoutDocument: Document, number: Int) {
        for (i in 0 until number) {
            layoutDocument.add(Paragraph(" "))
        }
    }

    private fun addDebitCredit(layoutDocument: Document, info: RPdfGeneratorModel) {

        val table = Table(
            UnitValue.createPointArray(
                floatArrayOf(
                    100f,
                    160f
                )
            )
        )

        table.addCell(Paragraph("Total Credit").setBold())
        table.addCell(Paragraph(info.totalCredit + ""))
        table.addCell(Paragraph("Total Debit").setBold())
        table.addCell(Paragraph(info.totalDebit + ""))
        table.addCell(Paragraph("Total Profit").setBold())
        table.addCell(Paragraph(info.totalProfit + ""))

        layoutDocument.add(table)
    }

    private fun addSubHeading(layoutDocument: Document, text: String) {
        layoutDocument.add(
            Paragraph(text).setBold()
                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
        )
    }

    private fun addLink(layoutDocument: Document, text: String) {

        val blueText: Text = Text(text)
            .setFontColor(ColorConstants.BLUE)
            .setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD))

        layoutDocument.add(
            Paragraph(blueText)
                .setAction(PdfAction.createURI(text))
                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                .setUnderline()
                .setItalic()
        )
    }

    private fun addTitle(layoutDocument: Document, text: String) {
        layoutDocument.add(
            Paragraph(text).setBold().setUnderline()
                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
        )
    }
}
```

RPdfGeneratorModel

```
class RPdfGeneratorModel(list: List<RTransaction>, header: String) {

    var list = emptyList<RTransaction>()
    var header = ""
    var totalCredit = ""
    var totalDebit = ""
    var totalProfit = ""

    init {
        this.list = list
        this.header = header
        calculateTotal(list)
    }

    private fun calculateTotal(items: List<RTransaction>) {
        val totalPlus = items.map {
            if (it.transType == RTransactionType.plus) {
                it.totalPrice
            } else { 0.0 }
        }.sum()

        val totalMinus = items.map {
            if (it.transType == RTransactionType.minus) {
                it.totalPrice
            } else { 0.0 }
        }.sum()

        val final = totalPlus - totalMinus
        totalDebit = "-" + totalMinus.toString()
        totalCredit = totalPlus.toString()
        totalProfit = final.toString()
    }
}
```

RTransaction model

```
enum class RTransactionType { plus, minus }

class RTransaction {

    var itemName: String = ""
    var custName: String = ""
    var transType: RTransactionType = RTransactionType.plus
    var pricePerUnit: Double = 0.0
    var quantity: Int = 0
    var totalPrice: Double = 0.0
    var transactionDateStr: String = ""

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

write below functions in your activity class for creating dummy data

```
private fun dummyModel(): RPdfGeneratorModel {
        val list = dummyTransactions()
        val header = "Statement"
        val dummy = RPdfGeneratorModel(list, header)
        return dummy
    }

    private fun dummyTransactions(): List<RTransaction> {

        val list = arrayListOf<RTransaction>()

        val i1 = RTransaction()
        i1.custName = "Johan Store"
        i1.itemName = "Snacks"
        i1.quantity = 4
        i1.pricePerUnit = 40.0
        i1.totalPrice = i1.quantity * i1.pricePerUnit
        i1.transactionDateStr = "10 Sep, 20"
        i1.transType = RTransactionType.plus
        list.add(i1)


        val i2 = RTransaction()
        i2.custName = "Alice Store"
        i2.itemName = "Chocolate"
        i2.quantity = 3
        i2.pricePerUnit = 79.0
        i2.totalPrice = i2.quantity * i2.pricePerUnit
        i2.transactionDateStr = "9 Sep, 20"
        i2.transType = RTransactionType.plus
        list.add(i2)

        val i3 = RTransaction()
        i3.custName = "Alexa Mall"
        i3.itemName = "Shoes"
        i3.quantity = 2
        i3.pricePerUnit = 177.0
        i3.totalPrice = i3.quantity * i3.pricePerUnit
        i3.transactionDateStr = "9 Sep, 20"
        i3.transType = RTransactionType.minus
        list.add(i3)

        val i4 = RTransaction()
        i4.custName = "Zainab Baba"
        i4.itemName = "Chips"
        i4.quantity = 5
        i4.pricePerUnit = 140.0
        i4.totalPrice = i4.quantity * i4.pricePerUnit
        i4.transactionDateStr = "8 Sep, 20"
        i4.transType = RTransactionType.plus
        list.add(i4)

        list.add(i1)
        list.add(i2)
        list.add(i3)
        list.add(i4)

        list.add(i1)
        list.add(i2)
        list.add(i3)
        list.add(i4)


        return list
    }
```

Now call RPdfGenerator function. Make sure to ask WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission before calling. For more details checkout [example project](https://github.com/rheyansh/RPdfGenerator)

```
val dummyInfo = dummyModel()
                RPdfGenerator.generatePdf(this, dummyInfo)
```

Comment: i used it but but i found itext tools not resolved  !

Answer (score 0):

I have used iText in a java swing application - it worked well to create some basic PDF files. The code goes something like this:

```
    @Override public void buildPDF(List<Folder> folders) {        
    Document document = new Document();
    String fname = "";
    boolean open = false;
    try {
            // step 2:
            // we create a writer that listens to the document
            // and directs a PDF-stream to a file
            fname = filename(getName()) + "-" + filename(getDataset().getName()) + ".pdf";

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                            new FileOutputStream(fname));

            for (int i = 0; i < folders.size(); i++ ) {
                // grab the folder
                LIFolder f = (LIFolder) folders.get(i);

                if (f == null) continue;

                open = true;
                break;
            }

            // we have no valid folders
            if (folders.size() > 0 && !open) {
                // they selected an empty row
                javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, BUNDLE.getString("report-none-selected"), 
                        BUNDLE.getString("report-none-selected-title"), 
                        javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }

            if (folders.size() == 0) {
                // get all folders from dataset
                folders = FolderFinder.findAll(getSession(), getDataset());
            }

            open = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < folders.size(); i++ ) {
                // grab the folder
                LIFolder f = (LIFolder) folders.get(i);

                if (f == null) continue;

                if (!open) {
                    open = true;
                    document.open();
                }

                Paragraph p = new Paragraph(BUNDLE.getString("report-heading-summary-main"), getPageHeadingFont());
                p.setAlignment("center");
                document.add(p);
                p = new Paragraph(BUNDLE.getString("report-heading-summary-main-sub"), this.pageHeadingFont1);
                p.setAlignment("center");
                document.add(p);

                blankLine(document);
                drawLine(writer);

                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Primary Statement Details
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////                    
                p = new Paragraph("Primary Statement Details", this.pageHeadingFont2);
                p.setAlignment("center");
                document.add(p);

                blankLine(document);
                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);

                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Dataset:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                BorderlessCell cell = new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(getDataset().getName(), getTextFont()));
                cell.setColspan(3);
                table.addCell(cell);

                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Data Entry Clerk:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                cell = new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(
                        (f.getDataEntryClerk() != null ? f.getDataEntryClerk().toDescriptionPathString() : emptyIfNull(null)), 
                        getTextFont()));
                cell.setColspan(3);
                table.addCell(cell);

                table.setWidthPercentage(100);
                cell = new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Statement Number:", getFieldHeadingFont()));
                table.addCell(cell);
                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(f.getReferenceId(), getTextFont())));

                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Statement Date:", getFieldHeadingFont())));

                String strDate = "";
                java.util.Date date = f.getStatementDate();
                if (date != null) {
                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
                    strDate = formatter.format(date);
                }
                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(strDate, getTextFont())));

                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Statement Location:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                cell = new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(emptyIfNull(f.getTakerLocation()), getTextFont()));
                cell.setColspan(3);
                table.addCell(cell);

                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Statement keywords:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                cell = new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(emptyIfNull(f.getKeywords()), getTextFont()));
                cell.setColspan(3);
                table.addCell(cell);

                document.add(table);
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Statement Giver's Details
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////                    
                LIPerson p01 = null;
                Set<Actor> actors = f.getActors();
                Iterator iter = actors.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    Actor actor = (Actor) iter.next();
                    if (actor instanceof LIPerson) {
                        LIPerson person = (LIPerson) actor;
                        if (person.getReferenceId().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("p01") ) {
                            p01 = person;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                blankLine(document);
                drawLine(writer);
                p = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Statement Giver's Details", this.pageHeadingFont2));
                p.setAlignment("center");                        
                document.add(p);

                java.util.ArrayList giver = new java.util.ArrayList();
                if (p01 != null)
                    giver.add(p01);

                table = new PdfPTable(2);
                table.setWidthPercentage(100f);
                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Name of Statement Giver:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(ActorsToString(giver), getTextFont())));

                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Sex:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                if (p01 == null)
                    table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(emptyIfNull("TBD"), getTextFont())));
                else
                    table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph((p01.getSex() != null ? p01.getSex().toString() : ""), getTextFont())));

                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Tribe:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                if (p01 == null)
                    table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(emptyIfNull(null), getTextFont())));
                else
                    table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(
                            new Paragraph((p01.getEthnicityOrTribe() != null ? p01.getEthnicityOrTribe().toDescriptionPathString() : emptyIfNull(null)), 
                            getTextFont())));

                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Nationality:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                if (p01 == null)
                    table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(emptyIfNull(null), getTextFont())));
                else
                    table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(
                            new Paragraph((p01.getNationality() != null ? p01.getNationality().toDescriptionPathString() : emptyIfNull(null)), 
                            getTextFont())));

                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Marital Status:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(emptyIfNull(f.getMaritalStatus()), getTextFont())));

                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Education Level:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(emptyIfNull(f.getEducationLevel()), getTextFont())));

                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("County of Origin:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(emptyIfNull(f.getCountyOfOrigin()), getTextFont())));

                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Mother's Name:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(emptyIfNull(f.getMothersName()), getTextFont())));

                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Father's Name:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(emptyIfNull(f.getFathersName()), getTextFont())));

                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("# of Dependents:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(Integer.toString(f.getNumDependents()), getTextFont())));

                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Phone Number:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(emptyIfNull(f.getPhoneNumber()), getTextFont())));

                document.add(table);

                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Summary
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////                    
                blankLine(document);
                drawLine(writer);
                p = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Summary", this.pageHeadingFont2));
                p.setAlignment("center");                        
                document.add(p);
                p = new Paragraph(new Chunk(emptyIfNull(f.getSourceSummary()), getTextFont()));
                document.add(p);

                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Incident(s)
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////                                        
                Set<Act> acts = f.getActs();

                if (acts.size() > 0) {
                    // sort them by id
                    Hashtable map = new Hashtable();
                    Iterator it = acts.iterator();
                    String[] ids = new String[acts.size()];
                    int x = 0;
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        LIAct act = (LIAct) it.next();
                        String index = Integer.toString(act.getId());
                        map.put(index, act);

                        ids[x++] = index;
                    }
                    java.util.Arrays.sort(ids);

                    blankLine(document);
                    drawLine(writer);
                    p = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Act(s)", this.pageHeadingFont2));
                    p.setAlignment("center");                        
                    document.add(p);

                    blankLine(document);
                    table = new PdfPTable(4);
                    table.setWidthPercentage(100);

                    for (int y = 0; y < ids.length; y++) {
                        LIAct act = (LIAct) map.get(ids[y]);

                        table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Act ID:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                        cell = new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(act.getReferenceId(), getTextFont()));
                        cell.setColspan(3);
                        table.addCell(cell);

                        table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Start Date:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                        table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph((act.getWhen() != null ? act.getWhen().toString():""), getTextFont())));

                        table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("End Date:", getFieldHeadingFont())));
                        table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph((act.getUntil() != null?act.getUntil().toString():""), getTextFont())));

                        table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Location of act:", getFieldHeadingFont())));                            
                        p = new Paragraph(emptyIfNull(act.getWhere().toString()), getTextFont());
                        p.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
                        cell = new BorderlessCell(p);
                        cell.setColspan(3);                            
                        table.addCell(cell);

                        table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Precise Location:", getFieldHeadingFont())));                            
                        p = new Paragraph(emptyIfNull(act.getPreciseLocation()), getTextFont());
                        p.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
                        cell = new BorderlessCell(p);
                        cell.setColspan(3);                            
                        table.addCell(cell);

                        table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Violation:", getFieldHeadingFont())));                            
                        p = new Paragraph(emptyIfNull(act.getViolation().toDescriptionPathString()), getTextFont());
                        p.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
                        cell = new BorderlessCell(p);
                        cell.setColspan(3);                            
                        table.addCell(cell);

                        table.addCell(new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph("Description:", getFieldHeadingFont())));                                         
                        p = new Paragraph(emptyIfNull(act.getDescriptionLocation()), getTextFont());
                        p.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
                        cell = new BorderlessCell(p);
                        cell.setColspan(3);                            
                        table.addCell(cell);

                        // add empty cell
                        cell = new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(""));
                        cell.setColspan(4);
                        table.addCell(cell);                            
                        cell = new BorderlessCell(new Paragraph(""));
                        cell.setColspan(4);
                        table.addCell(cell);                            
                    }

                    document.add(table);
                }                    

                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Victims
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                List<Actor> victims = this.getAllVictims(f);

                if (!victims.isEmpty()) {
                    blankLine(document);
                    drawLine(writer);
                    String strVictims = ActorsToString(victims);
                    p = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Victim(s)", this.pageHeadingFont2));
                    p.setAlignment("center");                        
                    document.add(p);

                    p = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Name(s) of Victim(s): ", getFieldHeadingFont()));
                    p.add(new Chunk(strVictims, getTextFont()));
                    document.add(p);

                    String gender = ActorsToGender(victims);
                    p = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Gender: ", getFieldHeadingFont()));
                    p.add(new Chunk(gender, getTextFont()));
                    document.add(p);
                }

                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Perps
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                List<Actor> perps = this.getAllPerpetrators(f);
                if (!perps.isEmpty()) {
                    blankLine(document);
                    drawLine(writer);
                    p = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Perpetrator(s)", this.pageHeadingFont2));
                    p.setAlignment("center");                        
                    document.add(p);

                    String strPerps = ActorsToString(perps);
                    p = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Name(s) of alleged perpetrator(s): ", getFieldHeadingFont()));
                    p.add(new Chunk(strPerps, getTextFont()));
                    document.add(p);
                }
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                document.newPage();
            }

    } catch (DocumentException de) {
            System.err.println(de.getMessage());
    } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }

    // step 5: we close the document
    if (open) {
        document.close();

        if (!fname.equals("")) {
            // launch it
            Reports.LaunchPDF(fname);        
        }
    }        

}
```

If you need more info, let me know. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Tarrant, I want to create an PDF file in android application not in java swing.

Comment: I am using simple code to create a pdf file in my sd card using iText pdf library, but it is giving following errors.


**1.** Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfGraphics2D', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.createGraphics

**2.** Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPrinterGraphics2D', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.createPrinterGraphics


**3. ERROR/dalvikvm(309)**: Could not find class 'org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSEnvelopedData', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptedDocObj

Comment: I'm assuming you've added the library to your project. I think you may need to run dx (in android sdk) on the jar file since unless you are using Eclipse? Dx is used to turn class files in a non-android jar into dex files so that they can be found/used on the device.

Comment: Yes i have added library to my project & i am using eclipse as IDE.Could you please share version of iText you have used? as iText 5.0.7 is for developing apps on android but its not free.They are charging around $1500 for license. Do you have any other open source pdf library for android.Please share if you know any.

Comment: I used iText 2.0.6. I believe it was open source back then.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.cete.androidexamples.dynamicpdf.helloworld;

import com.cete.dynamicpdf.*;
import com.cete.dynamicpdf.pageelements.Label;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DynamicPDFHelloWorld extends Activity {
    private static String FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/HelloWorld.pdf";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Create a document and set it's properties
        Document objDocument = new Document();
        objDocument.setCreator("DynamicPDFHelloWorld.java");
        objDocument.setAuthor("Your Name");
        objDocument.setTitle("Hello World");

        // Create a page to add to the document
        Page objPage = new Page(PageSize.LETTER, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT,
                54.0f);

        // Create a Label to add to the page
        String strText = "Hello World...\nFrom DynamicPDF™ Generator "
                + "for Java\nDynamicPDF.com";
        Label objLabel = new Label(strText, 0, 0, 504, 100,
                Font.getHelvetica(), 18, TextAlign.CENTER);

        // Add label to page
        objPage.getElements().add(objLabel);

        // Add page to document
        objDocument.getPages().add(objPage);

        try {
            // Outputs the document to file
            objDocument.draw(FILE);
            Toast.makeText(this, "File has been written to :" + FILE,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Error, unable to write to file\n" + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**add DynamicPDF to  libs files
you can downloade it from  [link](http://www.dynamicpdf.com/Products/DynamicPDFforJava/Download.csp)**

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument;  
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    
    
        private void designFile(){
    
    int pageHeight = 2200;
        int pagewidth = 1240;
    
    
      bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pizza);
            bitbip = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 1100, 700, true);
    
    
        PdfDocument    document = new PdfDocument();
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            Paint paint2= new Paint();
    
    
            PdfDocument.PageInfo mypageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(pagewidth, pageHeight, 2).create();
    
            PdfDocument.Page myPage = document.startPage(mypageInfo);
    
            Canvas canvas = myPage.getCanvas();
    
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 350, 10, paint);
    
          paint2.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
            paint2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint2.setTextSize(30);
            paint2.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            canvas.drawText("INSTAGRAM", 150, 125, paint2);
    
       document.finishPage(myPage);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).