# How can I use itextpdf.jar in Android for view pdf file?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - Load PDF / PDF Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468621/android-load-pdf-pdf-viewer)

I want to read pdf files in my App. So I use itextPDF but it will not work.

How can I use itextPDF.jar in Android?

Comment: I have edited my answer.verify it

Answer (score 3):

You can refer [this](http://code.google.com/p/ebookdroid/) for reading PDF files. It has included MuPDF, a lightweight PDF and XPS viewer. Hope this may useful to you.

Comment: how can i include in my project ? can u plse help me ?

Comment: Sure, you download source for same??

Comment: You can download from this link http://ebookdroid.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ using SVN checkout.

Answer (score 2):

`itextPDF.jar` will work only for creating pdf file in android device.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435103/how-to-create-pdf-file-using-itext-or-some-other-library-on-android) for creating pdf files in android device

Check this for [PDF viewing easier from within your Android application](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library)

Comment: but i want to open PDF in my application also android os without a adobe reader.

Answer (score 1):

**As Ram Kiran Sugguest it is not used for reading purpose** . You can use [APV PDF Viewer](http://code.google.com/p/apv/) library for view pdf .

Comment: @Nithinlal Download Source Code  - http://code.google.com/p/apv/downloads/detail?name=apv-0.3.3dev01.tar.gz&can=2&q=

Comment: thank u. I will check and replay

Comment: i got a error as atcx.hell.android.pdfview.OpenFileActivity.getPDF(OpenFileActivity.java:541)

Comment: Ok. can u say any other method ?

Answer (score 1):

tyr this

```
package android.test;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        File file=new File("/sdcard/bill.pdf");
                        if(file.exists())
                        {
                              Uri path=Uri.fromFile(file);
                              Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                              intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");

                              try
                              {

                                    startActivity(intent);
                              }
                              catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
                              {
                                    Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "No software for PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              }
                        }
                  }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: while using this code i want to install  adobe reader.so can u sent another method for read PDF ?