# FileNotFoundException : Can't Open file, file not found in Android

Tags: android, file-not-found, writefile

I am going to create one .pdf file and I am getting  file not found exception. I have written `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission for that in `AndroidManifest.xml` file and also provided runtime permission for Marshmallow device.

Below is my code:

```
 File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 //create a new file, to save the downloaded file
 File file = new File(SDCardRoot + "xyz/", pdfFilename);
 if (!file.exists()) {
     file.mkdir();
 }
 OutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
 docWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fileOutput);
```

Can you please get me out?

Comment: Yes, that was missing but I corrected it. and it was still not working :-(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239026/how-to-create-a-file-in-android

Comment: `file.mkdir();`. Check the return value as it might fail to create the directory in which case it returns false. If so then didplay a toast to the user saying so and return. Dont continue with the code then as it makes little sense trying to create a file in a directory that does not exist.

Comment: mkdir will create a directory with the pdf filename as folder. You should first create the xyz directory and then set up a File object using the file name.

Comment: I got the solution this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/8955442/4795817 helps me to create pdf file in sdcard

Comment: Thank you all of you for your efforts and all your suggestions, guidelines and help. Thanks